# Google chrome font rendering issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts, font-family

While developing my website, I noticed how Chrome was rendering my fonts (Roboto).

Long story short, here is a Screen shot of both the browsers:

IE/Firefox:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEZWb.jpg

Chrome:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NTwY.jpg

Checked the website in m y friends' pc too, but the bug is still there. My chrome version is 44.0.2403.125 and the font-face is Roboto. What to do?

Comment: Try to add the following css rule to your text: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you download the roboto font to your computer by any chance? I had a similar problem where I downloaded and installed a font to my computer, but it was bolder than the font I had been using with google fonts for my website, and after I installed the bolder font version, the font on my website also became bolder. I discovered that chrome is set to use locally stored versions of fonts with the same name wherever possible.

The solution was to un-install the bolder font version stored on my computer and refresh the cache.

Comment: Thanks! That helped, I deleted the Roboto font from ny local machine.